# Count specified character from field(s) in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that recorded data like following:

```
_____|__A__|__B__
__1__|__x__|_____
__2__|__x__|_____
__3__|__y__|_____
__4__|__x__|_____
__5__|__x__|_____
__6__|__y__|_____
__7__|__x__|_____
__8__|__ __|_____
__9__|__x__|_____
_10__|__y__|_____
_11__|__ __|_____
_12__|__x__|_____
```

I would like to count all field contained 'y' and ' ' from A1 to A12. Here's what I did for now:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A12, "y") + COUNTIF(A1:A12, "")
```

It will become longer if I count more specified character...
Would you suggest any better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this shorthand to achieve your result

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A12,{"y",""}))
```

This is exactly the same as

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A12, "y") + COUNTIF(A1:A12, "")
```

The shorthand allows you to easily add more characters you want to count.

You can read more about this here:

https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/

Comment: It works ! But I'm just wondering why it become 3, if I didn't add the SUM().

Comment: COUNTIF(A1:A12,{"y",""})      ->      3

Comment: You need to think of it as the two separate `countif` statements, so it is only returning the first `countif` result, and ignoring the second, so I think the `sum` tells excel I want both values, and add them up. At least, that's how I interpret it.